# ArcGIS Javascript example for geometry services?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry-service

I have a client that wishes to show him all the geometry services example in Javascript API

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISSERVER/10.0/APIS/REST/geometryserver.html

...

I'm new to Javascript and ArcGIS, is there a sample with all the examples for geometry services?

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/util_buffergraphic.html

Yes I have been here

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/

but they don't have all example.

Answer (score 5):

This is a list of all samples that are using the GeometryService: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/#search/GeometryService

The Javascript API has a handy feature where you can go to the class that you are interested in and click on samples, this creates a search for that class in the samples area.  Scroll down about a 1/2 a page on this link and see what I mean: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice.html